# Getting my k8s microservice application's non-namespaced dependancies

Tags: kubernetes, containers, microservices, client-go, kubernetes-go-client

If I have a microservice app within a namespace, I can easily get all of my namespaced resources within that namespace using the k8s api. I cannot, however, view what non-namespaced resources are being used by the microservice app. If I want to see my non-namespaced resources, I can only see them all at once, with no indication of which ones are dependancies in the microservice app.

How can I find my dependancies related to my application? I'd like to be able to get reference to things like PersistentVolumes, StorageClasses, ClusterRoles, etc. that are being used by the app's namespaced resources.

Comment: I haven't seen a tool like this yet. But maybe k9scli can. I didn't take a detailed view yet.

Comment: So your whole application is in only one namespace. Are you using any labels/selectors in those namespaces resources? Do you have anything else in this particular namespace? There is easy way to list all non-namespaced resources but list only with dependencies with specific namespace might be rough.

Comment: @PjoterS I was hoping for a solution that was not dependent on labels/selectors in case you wanted to use this method for an application that you did not make yourself. Namespaced resources I can certainly do, haven't found something for non-namespaced yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, running in a pod container inside a namespace, runs using a **serviceaccount** set using pod.spec.serviceAccountName.
*If not set, it'll run using the default serviceaccount*.

You need to create a **clusterRole** in order to grant access to cluster-wide resources specific verbs, then in the pod namespace assign this clusterRole to the serviceaccount, via a **roleBinding** targetting the clusterRole create before.

Then your pod, using a kubernetes client, and using the "in-cluster config" auth method, will be able to query the apiserver to get/list/watch/delete/patch... the said cluster-wide resources.

Comment: what would a query like this look like? It would be able to distinguish only the resources being used by my application? I can't find a query on the apiserver that looks like it would do this.

Comment: it sounds like what your really want is some kind of tracing combined with a graph you'd build from your pod name, then via ownerref fing the parent, and its parents. Then you'd query for services having your pod labels as selector. THen you'd query for pvc used by your pod and find it's pv and so on...

Comment: Since there is no reference back to the non-namespaced resources, would they have to all be found individually based on type? For PV I could use the PVC, but for clusterroles I'd need to query for all of them and sort out the ones not related to the application. For volumes I'd need to look at all resources for volumeMounts. Each non-namespaced resource type would have a unique way to search for them.

Comment: Yes, it'd be quite tedious

Answer (score 0):

This is a definitely a non-trivial task because of the many ways such `dependency` can come into play: whenever an object "uses" another one, there we could identify a dependency. The issue is that this "use" relation can take many forms: e.g., a `Pod` can reference a `Volume` in its definition (which would be a sort of direct dependency), but can also use a `PersistentVolumeClaim` which would then instantiate a `PV` through use of a `StorageClass` -- and these relations are only known to Kubernetes at *run* time, when the YAML definitions are applied.

In other words:

- To chase dependencies, you would have to inspect the YAML description of resources in-use, knowing the semantics of each: there's no single `depends:` value in each but one would need to follow e.g., the `spec.storageClass` of a `PVC`, the `spec.volumes:` of a `Pod`, etc.
- In some cases, this would not even be enough: e.g., for matching `Services` and `Pods` this would not even be enough, as one would have to match ports on each side.
- All of this would need to be done by extracting YAML from a running K8s cluster, since some relations between resources would not be known until they are instantiated.

You could check [How do you visualise dependencies in your Kubernetes YAML files?](https://learnk8s.io/visualise-dependencies-kubernetes) article by Daniele Polencic shows a few tools that can be used to visualize dependencies:

> There isn't any static tool that analyses YAML files. But you can visualise your dependencies in the cluster with [Weave Scope](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope), [KubeView](https://github.com/benc-uk/kubeview) or tracing the traffic with [Istio](https://istio.io/).